# Writing tests for mongoose models: best practices?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing a mongoose model called Category with the required fields name, description and URL.

I want to do this in the context of TDD with mocha + chai and here's my first test for the name field:

```js
const assert = require("chai").assert;
const Category = require("../category.model");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

describe("The category model", () => {
  describe("name", () => {
    it("returns an error if missing", async () => {
      const categoryWithoutName = new Category();
      let errorBundle;
      await categoryWithoutName
        .validate()
        .catch((error) => (errorBundle = error));
      assert.instanceOf(errorBundle, mongoose.Error.ValidationError);
      assert.isDefined(errorBundle.errors.name);
    });

    it("returns an error if the name is not a string", async () => {
      const categoryWithWrongNameType = new Category({ name: 1 });
      let errorBundle;
      await categoryWithWrongNameType
        .validate()
        .catch((error) => (errorBundle = error));
      assert.instanceOf(errorBundle, mongoose.Error.ValidationError);
      assert.isDefined(errorBundle.errors.name);
    });

    it("does not returns an error if provided", async () => {
      const categoryWithName = new Category({ name: "Gardening" });
      let errorBundle;
      await categoryWithName.validate().catch((error) => (errorBundle = error));
      assert.isUndefined(errorBundle);
    });
  });
});
```

And the accompanying code:

```js
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const categoryModel = {
      name: { type: String, required: true, cast: false },
    };
    
    const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(categoryModel);
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

As you can see, I've already come up with 3 tests just for the name field with this approach.

I therefore wonder if there are better approaches or best practices when testing mongoose models. Should we even test them at all?

Thank you for any help in clarifying the matter.